# how to align three divs to meet responsiveness using bootstrap jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys I am having a problem here I am trying to display three div.

The out put suppose to be like this below
 [image]

**The assignment requirement say.**
Develop a single page responsive website according to the supplied mockups. The desktop version is to fill the entire height of a user's browser. Mobile to stack sections on top of each other. As far as functionality is concerned, clicking on the icons (cycling, shopping cart, knife and fork or art and design tour) will slide out the middle white panel containing additional information. The date input field is to incorporate a javascript/jQuery date picker of your choice.

my current project available in the link below
https://www.dropbox.com/s/igxahc9x19pcbfb/maboneng.zip?dl=0

please help me guys.

Comment: Don't link to external code; include the code in the question. If it's very long then (please!) trim it down. Reason: questions posted here should be independent from outside resources that may change or that may cease to exist.

Answer (score 2):

This should be very easy to do using the [bootstrap grid system](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/).

You need to wrap all three divs in a single container `row` and then you can add the grid classes to say how they should render on certain devices.

To say that they should take up the full width of the page on medium or smaller devices, you would add the class `col-md-12` To say that it should take up a third on larger devices, you would divide 12 by 3 and add that class: `col-lg-4`

So now you are looking at something like

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="yourWrapper" class="row">
        <div id="panel1" class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">your html</div>
        <div id="panel2" class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">your html</div>
        <div id="panel3" class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">your html</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, to make them take up 100% height, just add `height:100vh;` to each of your divs

```
#yourWrapper > div {height:100vh;}
```